# Minimally Sufficient Statistic

Tags: statistical-inference

*In a nutshell, an example of a necessary and sufficient statistic is given in an article, but it is not explained there why the statistic is in fact necessary and sufficient. I'd appreciate help in understanding this.*

Bahadur ascribes to Lehmann & Scheffe the claim that there exists a minimally sufficient statistic on the statistical space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P=\left\{p\right\}\right)$ provided $P$ is separable under the metric $d\left(p,q\right):=\sup_{B\in\mathcal{A}}\left|p(B)-q(B)\right|$. ([BAH] last paragraph on p. 440, spilling over to p. 441.) He gives an example of a minimally sufficient statistic under these conditions, as follows.

Let $Q=\left\{q_1,q_2,\dots\right\}$ be a countable, everywhere dense subset of $P$. Choose a countable subset of $P$, $P_0=\left\{p_1,p_2,\dots\right\}$, such that every $\mathcal{A}$-$P_0$ null set (i.e. every set $B\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $p(B)=0$ for all $p\in P_0$) is also $\mathcal{A}$-$P$ null and vice-versa. The existence of $P_0$ is guaranteed by [HAL] lemma 7; alternatively [BAH] remark preceding theorem 6.1. Choose any sequence of positive, real constants that sum to $1$ and define

$$\lambda_0:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}},\space\space\lambda_0(B):=\sum_i c_i p_i(B)$$

$\lambda_0$ is a probability measure on $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A}\right)$. Set $\varphi_i:=\frac{dq_i}{d\lambda_0}$.

According to Bahadur, $T^*:=\left(\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\dots\right)$ is a minimally sufficient statistic for $P$. Unfortunately, he doesn't justify this claim, except by suggesting that "the construction is based on Theorem 6.1 and Corollary 6.1". I reproduce below these two results.

*Theorem 6.1* As defined, $\lambda_0$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{A}$ such that

1. $P\equiv\lambda_0$, i.e. each $P$-null set is a $\lambda_0$-null set and vice versa.
2. A necessary and sufficient condition that a subfield $\mathcal{A}_0$ be sufficient for the measures $P$ on $\mathcal{A}$ is that corresponding to each $p\in P$, there exists a nonnegative $\mathcal{A}_0$-measurable function $g_p$ such that $g_p=\frac{dp}{d\lambda_0}$ on $\mathcal{A}$.

*Corollary 6.1* Let there be given a $\sigma$-finite measure $\lambda$ on $\mathcal{A}$ such that $P\ll\lambda$. A necesary and sufficient condition that a statistic $T$ be sufficient for $P$ is that there exist a nonnegative function $h$ on $\Omega$ and a set $\left\{g_p:p\in P\right\}$ of nonnegative functions whose domain is the image of $T$ such that

1. $h$ is an $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function.
2. For each $p$, $g_p\circ T$ is an $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function.
3. For each $p$, $\frac{dp}{d\lambda}=h\cdot g_p\circ T$ on $\mathcal{A}$.

I understand why $T^*$ is a necessary statistic (this follows readily from [BAH] theorem 6.2 and corollary 6.2 (i), which i have not reproduced here), but why is it sufficient? Any help will be appreciated.

### References

1. [BAH] Bahadur, R. R. Sufficiency and Statistical Decision Functions. Ann. Math. Statist. Volume 25, Number 3 (1954), 423-462
2. [HAL] Halmos, Paul R., Savage, L. J. "Application of the Radon-Nikodym Theorem to the Theory of Sufficient Statistics". Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 20, 225-241 (1949)
3. [LEH] Lehmann E. L., Scheffé Henry. Completeness, Similar Regions, and Unbiased Estimation: Part I. ankhyā: The Indian Journal of Statistics (1933-1960), Vol. 10, No. 4 (Nov., 1950), pp. 305-340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be proved essentialy like theorem 6.3 in Lehmann E. L., Scheffé Henry. Completeness, Similar Regions, and Unbiased Estimation: Part I. Sankhyā: The Indian Journal of Statistics (1933-1960), Vol. 10, No. 4 (Nov., 1950), pp. 305-340